# Set image in button android

Tags: android, android-button, android-image

Hi i have set an image in button using the following code. But am failing to add multiple images to the button

```
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
```

any one can tell me how to set multiple images in button ?

Comment: multiple images for same button ?

Comment: @RajeshCP yes one below other.. any hope ?

Comment: You can change the image of the button , but I think you cannot set multiple images for the same button at same time.

Comment: Hope this is what you want

Answer (score 3):

You are passing wrong arguments to setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds..you need to pass resource ids ,while your are passing null for first three and drawable to fourth one..

You need to call

```
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.left,R.drawable.right,R.drawable.top,R.drawable.left.bottom)
```

From the android documentation

> ```
> Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable
> ```
>
> there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.
>
> Related XML Attributes android:drawableLeft android:drawableTop
>   android:drawableRight android:drawableBottom Parameters left  Resource
>   identifier of the left Drawable. top  Resource identifier of the top
>   Drawable. right   Resource identifier of the right Drawable.
>   bottom    Resource identifier of the bottom Drawable.

Comment: ok thanks  Akhil ..but i want to display 2 images one below another on right bottom..is it possible?

Comment: can u share expected image?

Comment: i just want put two images strips like red and orange one after other

Comment: yeah that's cool but i want put these strips based on conditions..like x==1 display red ..

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and do whatever customization you need..and setOnClickListner on it..

Answer (score -1):

You can use ImageButton or use background in normal button

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="20dp"
 android:layout_height="20dp"
 android:background="@drawable/noproductimage"
 />
```